# There is a way to run a embeded youtube player on TVs like Tizen or WebOS?

Tags: youtube-api, television, tizen-web-app, webos, youtubeplayer

There is a way to run a embeded youtube player on TVs like Tizen or WebOS?
And use it like a TV player, where the user can play and pause?

I'm developing a TV app to share my videos, and I don't to use advanced feature sof the TV player, I just wnat to get the youtube player and put this on my TV app... Is this possible?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm guessing your videos are in YouTube and you want to build an app showing your videos?

Comment: Yes, this is my exact scenario...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run a very simple YouTube HTML5 client developed by Amazon for their FireTV (it was developed to be embedded in an Android app but the HTML5 app can be used as a regular JavaScripts app)

Please check the project [here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/web-app-starter-kit-for-fire-tv) (you should check the youtube and youtube-sections apps)

Please, note for YouTube clients that uses the YouTube-API you must get your own API key and depending of the use of the app, some charges can be applied according the [guides](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3?hl=es-419)